# Python. Игра в актеры

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Всем привет, решил я сделать голосового помощника, пока-что текстовая версия, потом на голос переведу. Я в Яндекс Алисе увидел игру в актеров. Типа угадать актера по его характеристикам. Вот что у меня сейчас(P.S: Текст потом переделаю):

```
import time
import random 

name = input("Привет! Я Деласкер! Как я могу к тебе обращаться? ")
print("Привет", name, "! Чем я могу быть полезен?")


aktors = [
    'Леонардо Ди Каприо',#0
    'Бред Питт',#1
    'Джонни Депп',#2
    'Анджелина Джоли',#3
    'Двейн Джонсон',#4
    'Том Крузз',#5
    'Уилл Смит', #6
    'Николь Кидманн',#7
    'Меган Фокс',#8
    'Емиллия Кларк'#9,
    'Дженнифер Лопес',#10
    ]

aktor_facts = [
    'Американский актер, кинопродюсер. Лауреат премии «Оскар» за лучшую мужскую роль в фильме «Легенда Хью Гласса» и награды BAFTA и Гильдии киноактеров США за исполнение роли Хью Гласса.',#0
    'Американский актер, кинопродюсер. В 1996 году получил премию "Золотой глобус" за лучшую мужскую роль второго плана. В 2020 году получил Оскар за лучшую мужскую роль в фильме "Однажды в Голливуде"',#1
    'Aмериканский актер, продюсер, режиссер, сценарист, музыкант. В 2015 году вместе с Элисом Купером и Джои Перри актер создал музыкальный супергруппы под названием «Hollywood Vampires». Дебютный альбом группы вышел 11 сентября 2015.',#2
    'Aмериканская актриса, фотомодель, режиссер, посол доброй воли ООН, обладательница премии «Оскар» и трех премий «Золотой глобус». Дебютировала в кино в 1982 году, сыграв роль в фильме «В поисках выхода»',#3
    'Спортивное и сценическое прозвище Скала - американо-канадский актер, а также известный Реслер. С 1996 года по 2004 год выступал в World Wrestling Federation / Entertainment. С 2011 года вновь работает в WWE, выступая в основном на бренде Raw',#4
    'Американский актер, продюсер, режиссер, сценарист. Как один из самых высокооплачиваемых актеров современности, актер сыграл в большом количестве известных кинолент, которые пользовались неизменной популярностью в кинопрокате. Дебютом в кино актера считается эпизод в «бесконечной любви» ( 1981 ) Франко Дзеффирелли . Затем были еще несколько мелких эпизодов, в том числе в «Изгнанники» ( 1983 ) Копполы, однако настоящую популярность ему принесла роль богатого школьника, который влюбляется в проститутку, в комедии «Рискованный бизнес» ( 1983 ).',#5
    'Aмериканский актер, певец в стиле хип-хоп. Двукратный номинант на премию «Оскар», пятикратный - на премию «Золотой глобус». По итогам 2019 находится на 8-м месте рейтинга Forbes среди самых высокооплачиваемых актеров; его заработок составил $ 44500000.',#6
    'Австралийская актриса, одна из самых высокооплачиваемых звезд Голливуда. Лауреат премии «Оскар» 2003 года, четырехкратная обладательница премии «Золотой глобус», двукратная - прайм-тайм премии «Эмми», лауреат премии Гильдии киноактеров и многих других.',#7
    'Американская актриса и модель. Получила большую известность после исполнения роли Микаэлы Бейнс в фильмах «Трансформеры» и «Трансформеры: Месть падших».',#8
    'Британская театральная, телевизионная и киноактриса. Самая известная по роли Данерис Таргариен в телесериале «Игра престолов», за которую она четыре раза номинирована на прайм-тайм премию «Эмми»; лауретка премий «Сатурн», «Британия», «Грейси» и других.',#9
    'американская актриса, певица, танцовщица, модельер, продюсер и бизнес-вумен. Двукратная номинантка на премию «Золотой глобус». По итогам 2019 находится на 7-м месте рейтинга Forbes среди самых высокооплачиваемых актеров; ее заработок составил $ 47500000.'#10
    ]



def aktor():
    print('Я загадываю актера - вы отгадываете. У вас 5 попыток. Сыграем?')
    akchoice = input('Выбор: Да, Нет, Правила:')  
    if akchoice == 'Да':
        rndf = random.choice(aktor_facts)
        print(rndf)
        akchoice = input('Кто это?:')
        if rndf == 0 and akchoice == 0:
            print('Молодец! Ты угадал!')
        if rndf == 1 and akchoice == 1:
            print('Молодец! Ты угадал!')
        if rndf == 2 and akchoice == 2:
            print('Молодец! Ты угадал!')
        if rndf == 3 and akchoice == 3:
            print('Молодец! Ты угадал!')
        if rndf == 4 and akchoice == 4:
            print('Молодец! Ты угадал!')
        if rndf == 5 and akchoice == 5:
            print('Молодец! Ты угадал!')
        if rndf == 6 and akchoice == 6:
            print('Молодец! Ты угадал!')
        if rndf == 7 and akchoice == 7:
            print('Молодец! Ты угадал!')
        if rndf == 8 and akchoice == 8:
            print('Молодец! Ты угадал!')
        if rndf == 9 and akchoice == 9:
            print('Молодец! Ты угадал!')
        if rndf == 10 and akchoice == 10:
            print('Молодец! Ты угадал!')
        else:
            print('Не правильно!')
```

Я пробовал какую-то штуку сделать, не получалось. Как сделать чтобы например факты про Бредда Питта, ты ввел его имя и написало: Молодец! Правильный ответ?

Comment: Лучше сделайте список кортежей, в каждом кортеже пусть будет имя актёра и его описание. Рандомом выбирайте кортеж из списка, описание показывайте, а имя актёра сравнивайте потом с введённым.

Comment: А в вашем варианте зачем столько сравнений типа `if rndf == 0 and akchoice == 0:`, вы могли бы просто написать `if rndf == akchoice:` вместо всех этих вариантов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
import random 

name = input("Привет! Я Деласкер! Как я могу к тебе обращаться? ")
print("Привет", name, "! Чем я могу быть полезен?")


aktors = [
    'Леонардо Ди Каприо',#0
    'Бред Питт',#1
    'Джонни Депп',#2
    'Анджелина Джоли',#3
    'Двейн Джонсон',#4
    'Том Крузз',#5
    'Уилл Смит', #6
    'Николь Кидманн',#7
    'Меган Фокс',#8
    'Емиллия Кларк'#9,
    'Дженнифер Лопес',#10
    ]

aktor_facts = [
    'Американский актер, кинопродюсер. Лауреат премии «Оскар» за лучшую мужскую роль в фильме «Легенда Хью Гласса» и награды BAFTA и Гильдии киноактеров США за исполнение роли Хью Гласса.',#0
    'Американский актер, кинопродюсер. В 1996 году получил премию "Золотой глобус" за лучшую мужскую роль второго плана. В 2020 году получил Оскар за лучшую мужскую роль в фильме "Однажды в Голливуде"',#1
    'Aмериканский актер, продюсер, режиссер, сценарист, музыкант. В 2015 году вместе с Элисом Купером и Джои Перри актер создал музыкальный супергруппы под названием «Hollywood Vampires». Дебютный альбом группы вышел 11 сентября 2015.',#2
    'Aмериканская актриса, фотомодель, режиссер, посол доброй воли ООН, обладательница премии «Оскар» и трех премий «Золотой глобус». Дебютировала в кино в 1982 году, сыграв роль в фильме «В поисках выхода»',#3
    'Спортивное и сценическое прозвище Скала - американо-канадский актер, а также известный Реслер. С 1996 года по 2004 год выступал в World Wrestling Federation / Entertainment. С 2011 года вновь работает в WWE, выступая в основном на бренде Raw',#4
    'Американский актер, продюсер, режиссер, сценарист. Как один из самых высокооплачиваемых актеров современности, актер сыграл в большом количестве известных кинолент, которые пользовались неизменной популярностью в кинопрокате. Дебютом в кино актера считается эпизод в «бесконечной любви» ( 1981 ) Франко Дзеффирелли . Затем были еще несколько мелких эпизодов, в том числе в «Изгнанники» ( 1983 ) Копполы, однако настоящую популярность ему принесла роль богатого школьника, который влюбляется в проститутку, в комедии «Рискованный бизнес» ( 1983 ).',#5
    'Aмериканский актер, певец в стиле хип-хоп. Двукратный номинант на премию «Оскар», пятикратный - на премию «Золотой глобус». По итогам 2019 находится на 8-м месте рейтинга Forbes среди самых высокооплачиваемых актеров; его заработок составил $ 44500000.',#6
    'Австралийская актриса, одна из самых высокооплачиваемых звезд Голливуда. Лауреат премии «Оскар» 2003 года, четырехкратная обладательница премии «Золотой глобус», двукратная - прайм-тайм премии «Эмми», лауреат премии Гильдии киноактеров и многих других.',#7
    'Американская актриса и модель. Получила большую известность после исполнения роли Микаэлы Бейнс в фильмах «Трансформеры» и «Трансформеры: Месть падших».',#8
    'Британская театральная, телевизионная и киноактриса. Самая известная по роли Данерис Таргариен в телесериале «Игра престолов», за которую она четыре раза номинирована на прайм-тайм премию «Эмми»; лауретка премий «Сатурн», «Британия», «Грейси» и других.',#9
    'американская актриса, певица, танцовщица, модельер, продюсер и бизнес-вумен. Двукратная номинантка на премию «Золотой глобус». По итогам 2019 находится на 7-м месте рейтинга Forbes среди самых высокооплачиваемых актеров; ее заработок составил $ 47500000.'#10
    ]



def aktor():
    print('Я загадываю актера - вы отгадываете. У вас 5 попыток. Сыграем?')
    akchoice = input('Выбор: Да, Нет, Правила:')  
    if akchoice == 'Да':
        rndf = random.choice(aktor_facts)
        print(rndf)
        akchoice = input('Кто это?: ')
        key_words = set(map(str.upper, akchoice.split()))
        akname = aktors[aktor_facts.index(rndf)]
        akname_kw = set(map(str.upper, akname.split()))
        if key_words == akname_kw:
            return 'Вы угадали!'
        else:
            return 'Неправильно!'
for i in range(5):
    print(aktor())
```

`str.upper` - это я использую метод `str` как `str.upper(value)`, то есть как функцию в `map`

Насколько я понимаю, примерно такое решение было нужно?

Comment: Также советую добавить цикл wile в функцию, иначе получается одна попытка.

Comment: Спасибо, если знаешь, подскажи как убрать None. Написано: Вы угадали!, а потом None

Comment: Я про while знаю, я просто не копировал его, он стоит)

Comment: Насчёт None не подскажу, потому как у меня он не появляется. Покажите как вы вызываете функцию aktor().

Comment: print(aktor()), по другому не работало (VS 2019)

Comment: @ExploseRester, а почему ты за меня не проголосовал?

Answer (score 1):

Дополнил предыдущий код.

```
import time
import random 

name = input("Привет! Я Деласкер! Как я могу к тебе обращаться? ")
print("Привет", name, "! Чем я могу быть полезен?")


aktors = [
    'Леонардо Ди Каприо',#0
    'Бред Питт',#1
    'Джонни Депп',#2
    'Анджелина Джоли',#3
    'Двейн Джонсон',#4
    'Том Крузз',#5
    'Уилл Смит', #6
    'Николь Кидманн',#7
    'Меган Фокс',#8
    'Емиллия Кларк'#9,
    'Дженнифер Лопес',#10
    ]

aktor_facts = [
    'Американский актер, кинопродюсер. Лауреат премии «Оскар» за лучшую мужскую роль в фильме «Легенда Хью Гласса» и награды BAFTA и Гильдии киноактеров США за исполнение роли Хью Гласса.',#0
    'Американский актер, кинопродюсер. В 1996 году получил премию "Золотой глобус" за лучшую мужскую роль второго плана. В 2020 году получил Оскар за лучшую мужскую роль в фильме "Однажды в Голливуде"',#1
    'Aмериканский актер, продюсер, режиссер, сценарист, музыкант. В 2015 году вместе с Элисом Купером и Джои Перри актер создал музыкальный супергруппы под названием «Hollywood Vampires». Дебютный альбом группы вышел 11 сентября 2015.',#2
    'Aмериканская актриса, фотомодель, режиссер, посол доброй воли ООН, обладательница премии «Оскар» и трех премий «Золотой глобус». Дебютировала в кино в 1982 году, сыграв роль в фильме «В поисках выхода»',#3
    'Спортивное и сценическое прозвище Скала - американо-канадский актер, а также известный Реслер. С 1996 года по 2004 год выступал в World Wrestling Federation / Entertainment. С 2011 года вновь работает в WWE, выступая в основном на бренде Raw',#4
    'Американский актер, продюсер, режиссер, сценарист. Как один из самых высокооплачиваемых актеров современности, актер сыграл в большом количестве известных кинолент, которые пользовались неизменной популярностью в кинопрокате. Дебютом в кино актера считается эпизод в «бесконечной любви» ( 1981 ) Франко Дзеффирелли . Затем были еще несколько мелких эпизодов, в том числе в «Изгнанники» ( 1983 ) Копполы, однако настоящую популярность ему принесла роль богатого школьника, который влюбляется в проститутку, в комедии «Рискованный бизнес» ( 1983 ).',#5
    'Aмериканский актер, певец в стиле хип-хоп. Двукратный номинант на премию «Оскар», пятикратный - на премию «Золотой глобус». По итогам 2019 находится на 8-м месте рейтинга Forbes среди самых высокооплачиваемых актеров; его заработок составил $ 44500000.',#6
    'Австралийская актриса, одна из самых высокооплачиваемых звезд Голливуда. Лауреат премии «Оскар» 2003 года, четырехкратная обладательница премии «Золотой глобус», двукратная - прайм-тайм премии «Эмми», лауреат премии Гильдии киноактеров и многих других.',#7
    'Американская актриса и модель. Получила большую известность после исполнения роли Микаэлы Бейнс в фильмах «Трансформеры» и «Трансформеры: Месть падших».',#8
    'Британская театральная, телевизионная и киноактриса. Самая известная по роли Данерис Таргариен в телесериале «Игра престолов», за которую она четыре раза номинирована на прайм-тайм премию «Эмми»; лауретка премий «Сатурн», «Британия», «Грейси» и других.',#9
    'американская актриса, певица, танцовщица, модельер, продюсер и бизнес-вумен. Двукратная номинантка на премию «Золотой глобус». По итогам 2019 находится на 7-м месте рейтинга Forbes среди самых высокооплачиваемых актеров; ее заработок составил $ 47500000.'#10
    ]



def aktor():
    print('Я загадываю актера - вы отгадываете. У вас 5 попыток. Сыграем?')
    akchoice = input('Выбор: Да, Нет, Правила:')  
    if akchoice == 'Да':
        rndf = random.choice(aktor_facts)
        print(rndf)
        while True:
            akchoice = input('Кто это?: ')
            key_words = set(map(str.upper, akchoice.split()))
            akname = aktors[aktor_facts.index(rndf)]
            akname_kw = set(map(str.upper, akname.split()))
            print(key_words, akname_kw)
            if key_words == akname_kw:
                print('Вы угадали!')
                break
            else:
                print('Неправильно!')
aktor()
```

Comment: я немного по другому дополнил